# Does this whooping whistling cheering noise have a name?

Tags: single-word-requests

As audible in the first 27 seconds of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=0CBYgpV1Dgc&t=7s), and frequently heard on the intellectual powerhouse that is TV show [Take Me Out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_Me_Out_%28UK_game_show%29), people make this whooping whistling cheering noise – generally in vaguely hedonistic situations.

Does it have a name?

Comment: *Whooping? Whistling? Cheering?* They're all used as simple nouns to describe such noises.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes. I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe this exact noise. I feel it's common enough for the possibility of there being a word, phrase, or some slang to describe it specifically. Something akin to `wolf whistle`.

Comment: @Alec: I don't get you. The ***roar** of the crowd* is often used as a generic term covering many different noises (not just *roaring*), but ***wolf** -whistling*, for example, is a specific type of *whistling*. And *whistling* is a specific type of noise the audience might make. Are you asking for a single word covering all different types of ***vocal audience participation***?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Like `wolf whistle` conveys a specific whistle, I'm wondering if there's a word/phrase/slang that conveys the specific "woop woop" noise the audience in the linked video are making.

Comment: oic. I think that would be an exceptionally specific kind of "call and response" [Audience Participation Song](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AudienceParticipationSong). Surely the audience would only make that particular noise when they recognise that *particular* song? But perhaps there are lots of ["woot woot" disco songs](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22woot+woot%22+disco+music&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=#hl=en&q=%22woot+woot%22+disco+songs)

Comment: If you're referring to "uah, uah" chanting, I don't think there's any specific name for it, it's just a common chant made by partygoers at clubs or raves.  It goes back decades and I believe it has its roots in the rave movement but in any case I can remember it back all the way to the late 80's.

Comment: It predates rave, young one.  The "ooah, ooah" is from the 70's and was never given a name that I'm aware of - though it has evolved to "woot woot". It's a mimic of the standard whistle that appeared on lots of disco tunes.

Answer (score 1):

[Some sources](http://ask.metafilter.com/38195/Whoop-whoops) refer to this noise as the “disco call.” For example, it appears in the index of [*Turn the Beat Around: The Secret History of Disco*](http://books.google.com/books?id=GG1jtWGU0S8C&pg=PA358&lpg=PA358&dq=%22disco%20call%22%20whoop%20whoop&source=bl&ots=6_iaxb8Swj&sig=xFOF5UGnJWaTUsZ6x2SltL9HF7k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h6H1Usa8EobboAT8mYHQBA&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22disco%20call%22%20whoop%20whoop&f=false) as “‘Whoop! Whoop!’ (disco call),” and the Beastie Boys refer to it in their song [“Shake Your Rump”](http://www.metrolyrics.com/shake-your-rump-lyrics-beastie-boys.html):

> Oowah, oowah is the disco call

It looks like the the sound may have originally been referred to as **a** disco call, then later as **the** disco call, perhaps because it's the best-known example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that since you seem to be talking about a very specific sound people have been making only in the past few decades, an onomatopoeia  might suit your needs better.  I think a simple "whooOop - whooOOP" would probably work in context.

Answer (score 0):

The people that clap/whistle at performances are called a claque, but i don't know exactly if there is a word for exactly what they do. If there isn't, I think someone should invent a new word. Words that describe the question more generically might be: clap, whistle, wolf-whistle, cheer, enthusiastic support, roar of the crowd, etc..